# Google Maps V2 to V3 Marker Click Overlay Not Working (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, google-maps, overlay

I have been working on this one for a while now and I just cannot figure it out. I have google maps code that I am trying to bring into V3 from V2. I have everything working BUT the overlay that replaces the normal infowindow. This line:

```
$("#infoCallout").appendTo(map.getPane(G_MAP_FLOAT_SHADOW_PANE));
```

No longer works in V3. $("#infoCallout") is the hidden div. Right now the overlay just shows up on the top left...

See what I have so far here: http://empulseforum.com/brammoMapV3.php

And working in V2 just fine here: http://brammoforum.com/brammo-owners-map.php

I feel i am missing something easy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First, when I view the new site at your link, the page throws: **Uncaught ReferenceError: markerOffset is not defined** at line 73, which is (reformatted):

```
$("#infoCallout").fadeIn('slow').css({
    top:  markerOffset.y + -107,
    left: markerOffset.x - 40 });
```

It's easy to see that this code will never work without `markerOffset`, which is not defined because the code on the previous line (line 72) is commented out:

```
//var markerOffset = map.fromLatLngToDivPixel(markers.getPosition());
```

So, you have to uncomment the code on line 72 and refactor it to work via the v3 api:

1. The inner call: `markers.getPosition()` remains valid in v3; so far so good
2. The outer call: `map.fromLatLngToDivPixel()` no longer exists in v3; this and related calls have been moved into the class: `google.maps.MapCanvasProjection`. The projection is reachable by calling: `OverlayView.getProjection()`.

Bringing it together, I suggest you try changing the code in the `displayPoint` function to:

```
function displayPoint( markers, index ) {
    map.panTo( markers.getPosition() );
    $("#infoCallout").hide();
    updateMemberInfo( pic[index], dN[index], bID[index], cS[index] );

    // Next 2 lines are new and replace the old line of code:
    var prjctn = overlay.getProjection();        
    var markerOffset = prjctn.fromLatLngToDivPixel( markers.getPosition() );

    $( "#infoCallout" ).fadeIn( 'slow' ).css({
        top:  markerOffset.y + -107,
        left: markerOffset.x -40
    });
}
```

Obviously, this code is untested, so you may have some debugging to do, but I hope this code will get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use [OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView)'s `fromLatLngToContainerPixel` method.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I dont think its css either, I think it has something to do with adding the div (overlay) to the map "pane". I just cant figure it out.

Comment: That gets the position of the marker but doesnt help with the overlay.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that answer about CSS on the wrong question! You should display the Overlay within an OverlayView - then it will sit in relation to the map correctly.